# VBA Evaluate function with string arguments

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I have this function working ( It returns the row where the text DK001 sits in the ID range)

```
Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID=""DK001"",ROW(ID),""x"")")
```

I would like to feed the searchcriteria (e.g. DK001) as a string, like

```
Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID=SearchString,ROW(ID),""x"")")
```

I fail in creating a string that is accepted as a search criteria. I need your help on this! What am I doing wrong?

---

This Evaluate function is haunting me ....

What if I now wanted to send a value (not a string) to the function?

```
Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID=1,ROW(ID),""x"")")
```

The above works!

But if I want this to be a variable like

```
Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID=MyValue,ROW(ID),""x"")")
```

What then?

Comment: This Evaluate function is haunting me ....

What if I now wanted to send a value (not a string) to the function?

Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID=1,ROW(ID),""x"")")
The above works!

But if I want this to be a variable like

Found = Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID=MyValue,ROW(ID),""x"")")
What then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double `"` to include them as literals:

```
SearchString = "DK001"
Found = Application.Evaluate(""=IF(ID=""" & SearchString & """,ROW(ID),""x"")")
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I was trying to do the same, but inside the search string, but that failed. Appreciate your help and quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

With [`stdVBA`](http://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA) (an open source library largely maintained by myself) you can use `stdLambda` to accomplish this as follows:

```
set lambda = stdLambda.Create("if id.value = $1 then id.row else ""x""").bindGlobal("id",range("ID"))
'later...
Found = lambda("DK001")
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try

```
Application.Evaluate("=IF(ID="" & searchsrtring & "",ROW(ID),""x"")")
```

Comment: Will try this too, wait!

Comment: Nope! Get a Error 2029 back on this. But Alex suggestion worked. Thanks to you too for trying to help out!