# Executing VBA code from a string in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to execute VBA code, where the code itself is built from a string at runtime

I already found out how to do this via this existing SO answer:
[How to run a string as a command in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216390/how-to-run-a-string-as-a-command-in-vba)

For ease of reference, the solution is as follows:

```
Sub Testing()
    StringExecute "MsgBox" & """" & "Job Done!" & """"
End Sub

Sub StringExecute(s As String)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString "Sub foo()" & vbCrLf & s & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
    Application.Run vbComp.Name & ".foo"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub
```

In a nutshell, it creates a new module within the same workbook; writes a sub according to the specified string; executes the sub; and then removes the module - all within the same runtime process. This works well.

However what if I want to perform the operation on any other workbook than ThisWorkbook? I'm trying the following modified code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim NewWB As Workbook

Sub Testing()
    Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add
    StringExecute "MsgBox" & """" & "Job Done!" & """"
End Sub

Sub StringExecute(s As String)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Set vbComp = NewWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) ' Note the use of NewWB
    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString "Sub foo()" & vbCrLf & s & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
    Application.Run vbComp.Name & ".foo" ' <-- Error on this line
    NewWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub
```

As you can see, this code is identical but for the replacement of ThisWorkbook with NewWB. However it causes an error popup at the Application.Run line:

> *Run-time error '1004': Cannot run the macro 'Module1.foo'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.*

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work with a new workbook? I already tried adding a reference to VBA Extensibility to the NewWB via code after creating it (NewWB.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 5, 0) - however this did not help.

Comment: `Application.Run` will be looking for the module in the workbook creating the new workbook.  Try `application.run newwb.name & "!foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Run` will be looking for the module in the workbook creating the new workbook. Try (not fully tested) something along these lines:

```
application.run newwb.name & "!foo"
```

Comment: Thanks. You posted at the same time as me! If you add a close quote to your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Chris quote has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe it - after 18 hours of scratching my head over this, I post a SO question and then within 5 minutes I realise the answer myself.

The problem was with the syntax of Application.Run. Apparently, it can be used in the format [ModuleName].[ProcedureName] when running a procedure in the calling workbook; but to specify another workbook, the syntax should be [WorkbookName]![ProcedureName].

So all I had to do was change the line to read:

```
Application.Run NewWB.Name & "!foo"
```

I thought that instead of deleting my question I should just answer it :)