# Treat string as condition in VBA using Evaluate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string that is considered a condition and I tried using Evaluate (it works sometimes but not all the time). Have a look at the following example:
I got Error 2015

```
Sub Test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim result As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next 'Turn on error handling
    
    's = "7 > ""five""" 'Invalid comparison - expecting a numeric value
    s = "((7 > 5) And (10 < 15)) Or (Not (20 = 30))"
    
    result = Evaluate(s)
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Check for error
        Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Debug.Print result 'Output: False
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0 'Turn off error handling
End Sub
```

The question posted here too https://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=39654

In my code I will deal with more groups more than 3 and each group will have specific condition and I thought of storing the condition as string like that

```
Sub Test()
    Dim s As String, IGROUP As Long
    If IGROUP = 1 Then
        s = "a(x, 21) >= 25"
    ElseIf IGROUP = 2 Then
        s = "a(x, 21) = -1"
    ElseIf IGROUP = 3 Then
        s = "a(X, 21) <= 25 And a(i, 21) <> -1"
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the whole working code for me

```
Sub MyTest()
    Const IROWS As Long = 20
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, IGROUP As Long, m As Long, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long, n As Long
    Dim a, e, sAbsent As String, s As String, sHeader As String, j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sAbsent = Chr(34) & Chr(219) & Chr(34)
    a = shMY.Range("A2:U" & shMY.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    For IGROUP = 1 To 3
        k = 0: x = 0: n = 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 11)
        For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
            If IGROUP = 1 Then
                s = a(i, 21) >= 25
                sHeader = "Group1"
            ElseIf IGROUP = 2 Then
                s = a(i, 21) = -1
                sHeader = "Group2"
            ElseIf IGROUP = 3 Then
                s = a(i, 21) <= 25 And a(i, 21) <> -1
                sHeader = "Group3"
            End If
            If s Then
                k = k + 1: x = 1
                b(k, 1) = k
                For Each e In Array(2, 6, 3, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 21)
                    x = x + 1
                    b(k, x) = a(i, e)
                Next e
            End If
        Next i
        If k > 0 Then
            For i = LBound(b, 1) To UBound(b, 1)
                For j = 5 To UBound(b, 2)
                    If b(i, j) = -1 Then b(i, j) = Chr(219)
                Next j
            Next i
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("A8").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
        End With
            b = Application.Transpose(b)
    ReDim Preserve b(1 To UBound(b, 1), 1 To k)
    b = Application.Transpose(b)
        Dim subArr
        subArr = Split2DArray(b, 20)
           For i = LBound(subArr) To UBound(subArr)
           shNL.Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A5").Value = sHeader
            .Range("A8").Resize(UBound(subArr(i), 1), UBound(subArr(i), 2)).Value = subArr(i)
        End With
    Next i
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.Worksheets(1).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "RESULT-" & IGROUP & ".pdf"
        End If
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next IGROUP
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function Split2DArray(ByVal a, ByVal IROWS As Long)
    Dim subArrays, x As Long, y As Long, i As Long, ii As Long, k As Long
    x = UBound(a, 1): y = UBound(a, 2)
    ReDim subArrays(1 To Int(x / IROWS) + 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(subArrays) - 1
        ReDim subArr(1 To IROWS, 1 To y)
        For ii = 1 To IROWS
            For k = 1 To y
                If (i * IROWS + ii) > x Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    subArr(ii, k) = a((i * IROWS) + ii, k)
                End If
            Next k
        Next ii
        subArrays(i + 1) = subArr
    Next i
    Split2DArray = subArrays
End Function
```

what annoyed me is that I have to test the conditions for each iteration

```
    If IGROUP = 1 Then
        s = a(i, 21) >= 25
        sHeader = "Group1"
    ElseIf IGROUP = 2 Then
        s = a(i, 21) = -1
        sHeader = "Group2"
    ElseIf IGROUP = 3 Then
        s = a(i, 21) <= 25 And a(i, 21) <> -1
        sHeader = "Group3"
    End If
```

and I still have more groups to work on.

Comment: The first issue already arises as BigBen mentions when you try to use the logic you'd use in VBA in Excel. `7>5` and `10<15` both work but `((7>5) And (10<15))` does not (in Excel)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216390/how-to-run-a-string-as-a-command-in-vba

Comment: You will find that your working code is the correct and most efficient method.  The only other thing you could try is a Select Case instead of If/IfElse.

Comment: What is annoying for me is that these conditions will be checked for each iteration!!

Comment: "I have to test the conditions for each iteration" - how would you ever *not* do that though?  The rules for each IGROUP value are different, so you can't "save" the results for the next value...

Comment: I though of putting the lines of conditions as string before the loops `For IGROUP = 1 To 3`. That was my idea.

Answer (score 3):

[`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) doesn't evaluate text-that-looks-like-VBA.

If you do want to use `Evaluate`, then you can convert the logic to worksheet-formula syntax:

```
Evaluate("OR(AND(7>5,10<15),NOT(20=30))")
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot. But my condition, in reality, is more complex and it is `text-that-looks-like-VBA`.

Comment: Then `Evaluate` is the wrong tool.

Comment: I need to Evaluate VBA expressions as my line in the code looks like that
[code]If Replace(s, "X", i) Then[/code]

In the immediate window the result
[code]a(1, 21) <= 25 And a(1, 21) <> -1[/code]
and I need to Evaluate such a line. What can I do for such case?

Comment: [This is pretty much the only idea I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216390/how-to-run-a-string-as-a-command-in-vba)