# use string in equation

Tags: excel, vba, string, variables

I have a vba statement

```
fnb = "=RIGHT(t4,LEN(t4)-SEARCH(""_"",t4))"
```

This renders the appropriate Value when I assign the results to a cell, but I want to use the variable value within another equation. I'm trying to use the variable fnb:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=IF(COUNTIF(R[-1]C,""*Final*""),""RW_""&R7C20&R7C21&""_Final"",""RW_""&R7C20&R7C21&""_v""" & fnb & ")"
```

but when I execute it I get the value of fnb within the cell as the equation itself:

```
=RIGHT(t4,LEN(t4)-SEARCH(""_"",t4))
```

How do I phrase the statement to use the VALUE of the string instead of the equation?

Comment: You might want to try `EVALUATE`. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767103/vba-evaluate-function-with-string-arguments.